# Python list, iteration

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Hi I have the following problem about iterating about a common term in a list and writing it to a file, the list looks like this, I could save it differently for different pdfs,and now I trying to write it separately to csv files for different stocks? any one can help me again ,thank you

```
('AAPL', Timestamp('2012-10-22 16:00:00'), 669.78999999999996, 669.68011449859193),
('AAPL', Timestamp('2012-10-23 16:00:00'), 669.78999999999996, 669.68021661402906),
('AAPL', Timestamp('2012-10-24 16:00:00'), 669.78999999999996, 669.67977965494936),
('AAPL', Timestamp('2012-10-25 16:00:00'), 669.78999999999996, 669.67977965494936),
('AAPL', Timestamp('2012-10-26 16:00:00'), 669.78999999999996, 669.67977965494936),
('AAPL', Timestamp('2012-10-31 16:00:00'), 669.78999999999996, 669.67977965494936),
```

However there are also other stocks instead of AAPL, and this list is quite a long one, I am trying to write the plot the results of each stock in a pdf file. This code works for a single stock, how do I make it work for all the stocks in my list?.

```
 prediction = np.asarray(prediction_series)
  stocks = set(prediction[:,0])
  for stocki in stocks:
  p_stock = prediction[np.where(prediction[:,0] == stocki)]
  print p_stock.shape[0]
  predictionValues=  p_stock[:,2:4]
  predY=p_stock[:,2]
  actualY=p_stock[:,3]
    #predictionStock=prediction[:,1]
  dates=p_stock[:,1:2]


  writer = csv.writer(open('Predicted and Actual Y %s.csv' % stock, 'wb'), delimiter=',')
  for i in range(0,predY.shape[0]):

            row_to_enter = [dates[i],predY[i], actualY[i]]
            writer.writerow(row_to_enter)
  plt.clf()
  plt.plot(dates, predictionValues)
  plt.legend(ls)
  plt.ylabel('Predicted vs actual')
  plt.xlabel('Date')
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.where` to get the values that belong to some stock:

```
stocks = set(prediction[:,0])
for stock in stocks:
    p_stock = prediction[np.where(prediction[:,0] == stock)]
    # plot data from p_stock here
```

Note that this will filter the array multiple times, once for each stock. So in case you have many different stocks and the list is really big, you might instead use a dictionary, mapping stock names to lists, to filter the entire list in one pass.

Comment: Hey thank you so much, it worked :D :D, saved me a lot of trouble.thank you again

Comment: Hi, If I want to write the same way to a csv file? can you kindly explain me how? I did the following,but just getting the last stock.
writer = csv.writer(open('Predicted and Actual Y %s.csv' % stock, 'wb'), delimiter=',')
          for i in range(0,predY.shape[0]):
                  
                    row_to_enter = [dates[i],predY[i], actualY[i]]
                    writer.writerow(row_to_enter)

Comment: @ZenStan If you are only getting the last stock, are you sure that that code is _inside_ the for-stock-loop?